# Raphael JS and Java web app

Tags: java, javascript, raphael

I want to use the [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) Javascript framework to create some charts based on dynamic data coming from my Java web application. Is the only way to access this data from my web application through the use of hidden fields on my page which I can then lookup inside the Rapahel JS code?

Comment: what is your question?... I would presume that your Java code would generate the javascript (that would then make the chart) when you load the page

Comment: Did you find out how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

A typical approach would be for the web application to send a JSON file which your javascript would use to drive the Raphael library.

Reference:

1. [Using JSON in jQuery](http://www.jqapi.com/#p=jQuery.getJSON).
2. [Ajax Tutorials](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials)

Answer (score 0):

As Brock says above, then look at: http://www.highcharts.com/

Why reinvent the wheel?  Unless you want the experience.  Graphing is fun.